# How to save values in view controllers during app running? ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I got app with 2 view controllers, I'm typing values via `NSStrings` in Label and TextField in my first view controller and when I by pushing my navigation button go to my second view controller.
When I return to my first view controller, I got entered early values. But when next after that I go to my second view controller - values entered via `NSStrings` in Label and TextField disappear. How to fix this that the values ​​saved?
I tried to use strong and copy properties but that not helps me.

**UPDATE**
I use segue and storyboards, segue with modal type, I use 2 navigation controllers: for first view controller and for second. I got code only for modal type. First view controller  is root for navigation

**UPDATE**
I use 2 navigation controllers because I need modal segue from first VC to second and from second to first, when I use one navigation controllers that is not works like I need

Comment: post some code,so we can understand where you mistaking..

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: When you are using you navigation controller, are you `popping` the first view controller? If so that will put everything from the first view controller up for memory release, causing it to clear out.

Comment: if you are pushing and popping programmatically or presenting modally, you should write some code. If you are pushing and popping via segues in storyboard, the answers could be more clear for you. There's a big difference between these three ways.

Comment: I use segue and storyboards, segue with modal type, I use 2 navigation controllers: for 1 view controller and for second. I got code only for modal type

Comment: @ersentekin, First view controller is root for navigation

Comment: i'm sorry but why you use 2 different navigation controllers? You can navigate two view controllers with one navigation controller? You just need to add one navigation controller to the first view controller , then link your button in the first view controller (in storyboard) to second view controller via modal segue. If you do in this way, second view controller inherit your first view controller's navigation. So, your values do not disappear when you dismiss your second view controller.

Comment: @ersentekin, I use it because I need modal segue from first VC to second and from second to first, when I use one  navigation controllers that is not works like I need because at one moment button of second VC disappeared.

Comment: @ersentekin, do I need delete 1 VC to have result that I want?

Comment: you should delete second NAVIGATON CONTROLLER if you have. Totally, you will have 1 navigation controller, 2 view controllers

Comment: @ersentekin, data still not saved

Comment: @user3130451 you should post your code. maybe i can write a detailed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post some code otherwise we are just guessing. One guess is that you are using segues. Segues always create a new instance of the viewController. If you don't hold on to the old viewController somehow, it will get destroyed and any values it contained are also gone.
Just a guess.

Comment: I use segue, I update first post. If I will be hold on my first viewController , the values of viewController will be saved?

Comment: It depends on your design. If you rootViewController modally presents anotherviewController, it is not destroyed. When your modal viewController gets dismissed by your rootviewController (view controller NEVER dismiss themselves), the values should still be there. If you are talking about the values in the modally presented viewController, you should hand them to the presenting viewController before being dismissed, most likely via a delegate callback.

Comment: how can I hold on my first viewController?